# How to change Nexus 3 repository base url?

Tags: sonatype, nexus3

I need to set multiple dns to Nexus Repository Manager 3.

I tried setup nginx for url rewrite like below

```
https://npm.example.me/$1 -> http://internal-nxrm-dns/repository/npm-proxy/$1
https://nxrm.example.me/$1 -> http://internal-nxrm-dns/$1
```

But it not work appropriately.

Because, the return url included `/repository/npm-proxy`

```
curl https://npm.example.me/hello

"dist": {
    "integrity": "sha512-rkl8eXJVSGPHzLjzgLrf+tnexnewceyeF2fbP4Bv7839koHHtUy/YgG3hiY9+cuztGqGESGJStbPxF3EBg1GFA==",
    "shasum": "31fb25701fcfdf590daa27d875fe372ff3765898",
    "tarball": "https://npm.example.me/repository/npm-proxy/hello/-/hello-0.3.2.tgz"
  },
```

How do I change base prefix url of npm repository?

Comment: It isn't possible to change the web context path of an npm repository in Nexus Repo due to the way npm metadata works.

Comment: That's so sad news :(